# Compiler shouts The text ">" is unexpected C++ XLC

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, header, std

I have declared a function in my headerfile.

I have no clue why but the compiler moans about this line and says `"The Text ">"` is unexpected.

I'm using AIX 5.3 and a XLC/VAC Compiler. Maybe there is also something wrong with my definition of the function, but i assumed that the map has to know what the types are that it holds to work.

The problematic line is printed below.

```
std::map<std::string , std::list<std::pair<int, Event*> > * > * functionX(Customer * id, std::multimap<string, CustomerDetails> * p_mapWithCustomers);
```

I assume that this is a correct declaration of the function

As proposed below i have defined typedefs, unfortunately this has only shiftet the problem, now i get the same error on the line of the typedefs.

```
typedef std::pair<int, Event* > pair_event_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, pair_event_t * > map_rule_t;
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch

Comment: If you'd use some typedefs, you probably would find the type a lot easier to read, and I'd bet you would also find the error (if it didn't magically disappear when breaking down the type into manageable chunks)

Comment: "shouts", "moans", "assume" ... the compiler is telling you the declaration is incorrect, so you the compiler must be wrong? Either edit in the _new_ code (after Nim's fix) and the _new_ error, or take MSalters' advice to start naming your types.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can name my types? I have zero experience in that. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in an included definition file as soon as I took it out the error disappeared.

I have figured it out when i compiled it on windows in my eclipse it was throwing an unexpected sign in a macro definition error. The unexpected sign was also ">". Thanks everybody for contributing.

Oliver

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the `>>` unless you are using c++11, where this is valid, insert a space `> >`

```
std::map<std::string , std::list<std::pair<int, Event*> >*> * functionX(Customer * id, std::multimap<string, CustomerDetails> * p_mapWithCustomers);
```

Comment: Now that i done what you proposed it still says that but with one "The text ">" is unexpected"                                                        std::map<std::string , std::list<std::pair<int, Event*> >*> * functionX(Customer * id, std::multimap<string, CustomerDetails> * p_mapWithCustomers);

Comment: @OliverStutz - that line looks fine to me, may be you can post the entire error?

Comment: 1540-0063 (S) The text ">" is unexpected. This is all i have.

Comment: I would assume so, unfortunately what i have found on ibm was the following: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21051267 but i have no clue what that actually means and where i have to set the "template" which is described in the text.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with this particular line, but most likely to do with the types `Event`, `Customer` or `CustomerDetails`, I've never come across a situation where you have to use the `template` keyword in relation to a standard container.

Comment: I have very little knowledge about compilers, would it help to name my types, what do you think Nim, how would you try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The token `>>` is a separate operator from two consecutive `>` characters. Put a space between them.

C++11 fixes that, but if your compiler doesn't support the new standard, or if you haven't enabled that support, then you need to separate the characters so they're not confused for a `>>` operator, which has no place in template operations.

Answer (score 1):

After adding a space in the middle of `>>` maybe you need to add a `std::` qualification on that `string` in the declaration of p_mapWithCustomers.